# Error when trying to add domain which I deleted before. Yandex

Tags: yandex

I get this error when I try to add a domain which I have previously deleted from my Yandex account.

domain_must_be_migrated: Domain must be migrated from PDD

and 
Unable to complete action. A 422 error occurred.

I could not find any related issue in the documentation or google. could anyone give some advice regarding this issue, please?

Comment: Hi @ukeagle, im having the same issue and there is no information anywhere on documentation, could you get any solution?

Answer (score 1):

I also have the same problem with the long domain when i tried to add domain in to new oraganization. So i added another domain shorter (even i do not own it), it is success.

When i created a new organization, i add the correct domain into the organization

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and I contacted the Yandex customer support for the same but i did not get any resolution even after a month. 
So I just tried adding www.mydomain.com as a new organization instead of mydomain.com and it worked perfectly.